# ggplot barplot of each row (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
    a  b  a_total b_total 
dog 3  5  10      8
cat 6  2  12      13
pig 9  3  15      9
```

I'm trying to make a stacked barplot using ggplot to have "a_total" on the bottom and "a" on top for each animal. I tried this but doesn't work.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = c("a", "a_total")) + geom_bar(stat= "identity")
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a column from the row names (`rownames_to_column`), `select` the 'a' columns along with the new column, reshape to 'long' format (`pivot_longer`) and do the plotting

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
    rownames_to_column('animal') %>% 
    select(animal, a, a_total) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -animal) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = animal, y = value, fill = name)) + 
        geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
        theme_bw()
```

-output

[image]

---

Also, this can be done for both 'a' and 'b' in a `facet_wrap`

```
df %>%
     rownames_to_column('animal') %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -animal) %>%
     mutate(abgrp = substr(name, 1, 1)) %>% 
     ggplot(aes(x = animal, y = value, fill = name)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
       theme_bw() + 
       facet_wrap(~ abgrp)
```

---

In `base R`, we can use `barplot`

```
barplot(t(df[c('a', 'a_total')]), col = c('red', 'blue'), legend = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(3L, 6L, 9L), b = c(5L, 2L, 3L), a_total = c(10L, 
12L, 15L), b_total = c(8L, 13L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("dog", 
"cat", "pig"))
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the order of the two plots using facet_wrap by any chance? EX)to order it b a instead of a b?

Comment: @benefactor-anchovy32 you can change to `factor` i.e. `df %>%
     rownames_to_column('animal') %>%
     pivot_longer(cols = -animal) %>%
     mutate(abgrp = substr(name, 1, 1), abgrp = factor(abgrp, levels = c('b', 'a'))) %>%  ggplot(aes(x = animal, y = value, fill = name)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = 'identity') + 
       theme_bw() + 
       facet_wrap(~ abgrp)`

Comment: @benefactor-anchovy32 and for changing the order in legend use `guides` `guide_legend`